Margin content on the left side with tufte-book class
Is there a simple way to place all marginnotes and captions in a tufte-book environment in the left margin in stead of the right? If the class option twoside can do the job on every other page, I expect it is possible to do on all pages?
\documentclass[justified]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

This is some sample text with a margin note.\marginnote{Should be in the left margin.}

\lipsum[6]

\begin{figure}[h]
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}
   \caption{Should be in the left margin.}
   \label{fig:textfig}
\end{figure}

\end{document}



You can try to play with \reversemarginpar and \normalmarginpar. See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98130/316068.

It is possible to implement tufte like features in non tufte documents (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/666684/how-can-i-have-body-text-beside-a-float-in-the-margin for example).  IIRC, tufte is a traditional style, not just a cute idea.

Traditionally, the margins are on the outer side of the page. Here you have to set an appropriate geometry
\geometry{right=1in, left=\dimeval{14pc + 1in}}

and use
\reversemarginpar

to get \marginnote on the left side (\marginnote uses \marginpar behind).
But you need also to fool tufte-book on the page settings
\setboolean{@tufte@symmetric}{true}%
\renewcommand*{\@tufte@checkoddpage}{%
  \setboolean{@tufte@odd@page}{false}%
}

redefine the fullwidth environment
\renewenvironment{fullwidth}
  {\begin{adjustwidth}{-\@tufte@overhang}{}}%
  {\end{adjustwidth}}%

and fix the header with the oneside option and
\AtBeginDocument{\fancyhfoffset[RE, RO]{0pt}}

Example:
\documentclass[justified, oneside]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\geometry{right=1in, left=\dimeval{14pc + 1in}}
\reversemarginpar

\makeatletter
\setboolean{@tufte@symmetric}{true}%
\renewcommand*{\@tufte@checkoddpage}{%
  \setboolean{@tufte@odd@page}{false}%
}
\renewenvironment{fullwidth}
  {\begin{adjustwidth}{-\@tufte@overhang}{}}%
  {\end{adjustwidth}}%
\AtBeginDocument{\fancyhfoffset[RE, RO]{0pt}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This is some sample text with a margin note.\marginnote{Should be in the left margin.}

\lipsum[6]

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
   \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}
   \caption{Should be in the left margin.}
   \label{fig:textfig}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

This is some sample text with a margin note.\marginnote{Should be in the left margin.}

\lipsum[6]

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
   \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}
   \caption{Should be in the left margin.}
   \label{fig:textfig}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

This is some sample text with a margin note.\marginnote{Should be in the left margin.}

\lipsum[6]

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
   \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}
   \caption{Should be in the left margin.}
   \label{fig:textfig}
\end{figure}
\end{document}



Works like a charm, thanks! Can you show how to change the width of the margin (with the marginnotes and captions)? Thanks.

@DavidH \geometry{right=1in, left=\dimeval{14pc + 1in}} sets the margins with the values used by tufte-book, but left and right ones are swapped. Use any desired value, eg. \geometry{right=2cm, left=5cm}.
